# Declare class variable within class methods in C++

Tags: c++, python, class, oop, function

In python we may use self keyword to declare class variables within a member function of the class which can be subsequently used by other member functions of the class.
How to do such a thing in C++.

Python Code:

```py
class abc():
{ 
  def __init__(self):
    self.help='Mike' #self.help is the class variable and can be used in other methods
  def helpf():
    morehelp=self.help+' Bike'
}
```

C++ code:

```
 class abc
 {
   public: 
     abc();
   public: 
     void helpf(void);
 };
 abc::abc()
 {
   string help="Mike";       
 }
 void abc::helpf()
 {
   string morehelp=this->helpf+" Bike";// this keyword sounded like the one but...
 }
```

Comment: That's not quite Python, and your example is not a "class variable" it's an _instance_ variable

Comment: C++ is a statically-typed language whereas Python is a dynamically typed one. This fact allows you to to create instance variables in methods of a class by just assigning a value to them prefixed with `self.`. There's nothing equivalent in C++ -- all members must be declared before they can be referenced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do such thing in C++.
You should declare members in class, not in functions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare class members inside functions in C++. You have to declare them outside functions, like in JAVA

```
class abc
{
public: 
   int publicInt; // This is a public class variable, and can be accesed from outside the class
   int abc();
private: 
   float privateFloat; // This is private class variable, and can be accesed only from inside the class and from friend functions
   void helpf(void);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

that is not possible. Declaring variables inside a member function are local to that member function. If you want to use variables in your member function you have to declare class variables.

Answer (score 0):

This works in Python because Python allows you to add a attribute to an object from *anywhere* simply by assigning to it. It attaches to *that object*, rather than the object's class. In keeping with Python's dynamic language philosophy, and particularly with its lack of variable declarations, all of this - including the decision about which attributes do or don't exist - happens *at run time*.

C++'s explicitly does not have a concept of one particular object having an attribute - *all* member variables are associated with the class, even if they take independent values on each instance. The set of *all* possible member variables, and which types they hold, is shared class-wide and set in stone at compile time. Because of this, what you're asking for basically doesn't make sense in C++.